# How can i Parse custom mib(.mib) file using python pysnmp or pysmi and retrieve description related to a specific OID?

Tags: python, pysnmp

How can i Parse custom mib(.mib) file using python pysnmp or pysmi and retrieve description related to a specific OID?

```
from pysnmp.smi import builder, view, compiler

mibBuilder = builder.MibBuilder() 
compiler.addMibCompiler(mibBuilder, sources= 
['\\C:\\Users\\HP\\PycharmProjects\\FirstProgram\\SNMP\\venv\\lib\\site- 
packages\\pysnmp\\smi\\mibs\\','file:///home/user/python-udp/MIBs',
'http://mibs.snmplabs.com/asn1/'])`
mibBuilder.loadModules('RFC1213-MIB')
mibView = view.MibViewController(mibBuilder)
oid, label, suffix = mibView.getNodeName((1.3.6.1.2.1.8.1.0))
print(label)
```

Answer (score 0):

Exactly [the example](https://github.com/lextudio/pysnmp/blob/v6.0.5/examples/smi/manager/print-oid-description.py#L30) covers,

```py
from pysnmp.proto.rfc1902 import ObjectIdentifier
from pysnmp.smi import builder, view, compiler

# Create MIB builder
mibBuilder = builder.MibBuilder()

# Optionally compile MIBs
compiler.addMibCompiler(mibBuilder, sources=['/usr/share/snmp/mibs'])

mibBuilder.loadTexts = True

# Load MIB modules
mibBuilder.loadModules('SNMPv2-MIB')
# mibBuilder.addMibSources(builder.DirMibSource('/Users/lextm/pysnmp.com/pysnmp/mibs'))
# mibBuilder.loadModule('LEXTUDIO-MIB')

# Create MIB view controller
mibViewController = view.MibViewController(mibBuilder)

# Create an OID object
oid = ObjectIdentifier('1.3.6.1.2.1.1.3.0')

# Get the MIB name and symbol name for the OID
modName, symName, suffix = mibViewController.getNodeLocation(oid)

# Get the MIB node for the OID
mibNode, = mibBuilder.importSymbols(modName, symName)

# Get the description of the MIB node
description = mibNode.getDescription()

# Print the results
print('OID: %s' % oid)
print('MIB name: %s' % modName)
print('Symbol name: %s' % symName)
print('Description: %s' % description)
```